# Does SQL*PLUS has embedded PLSQL engine?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Could you please let me know whther the SQL*PLUS has embedded PLSQL engine?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. SQL*Plus does not have an embedded PL/SQL engine. All PL/SQL code is sent directly to the database PL/SQL engine for execution.